# How to make an array of buttons

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, button, stack

I have an ElevatedButton with certain parameters. I would like to make an array of ElevatedButton buttons with these parameters and specify the number of array elements, let's say 10 buttons, how can I do this?

```
  class ButtonWidget extends StatefulWidget {
   const ButtonWidget({Key? key,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ButtonWidget> createState() => _ButtonWidgetState();
}

class _ButtonWidgetState extends State<ButtonWidget> {

  Set<Color> getColorSet({int numberOfColor = 3}) {
  Set<Color> generatedColorSet = Set<Color>();
  while (generatedColorSet.length != numberOfColor) {
    generatedColorSet.add(
      Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
    );
  }
  return generatedColorSet;
}
  Set<Color> colorSet = Set<Color>();
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    colorSet = getColorSet();
  }
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      height: 140, 
      width: 200, 
      top: 25, 
      left: 5, 
      child: SizedBox(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(    
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(colorSet.elementAt(0)),
            overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(colorSet.elementAt(1)),
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular((200)),
                side: BorderSide(color: colorSet.elementAt(2), width: 5),
              ), 
            ),
            padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.all(10)),
            minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size(50,50)),    
          ),
              onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              colorSet = getColorSet();
            });
          },
          child: const Text(
            'PRESS',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), 
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The widget in which the button is located I placed inside the Stack.

```
   @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: [
           ButtonWidget( ),
            ],      
          ),
        );
      }
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can use: `List.generate(10, (_) => ButtonWidget())`

Answer (score 0):

**Dart represents arrays in the form of List objects.**

so to achieve your requirement you can create you custom button with reuired paramters and then can use listview builder to get multiple view.

example :

```
ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: 10,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return yourCustombutton();
 })
```